Black screen on kubuntu 22.10 and nvidia drivers
After installing fresh kubuntu 22.10 everything works normally. When installing nvidia drivers 560 (I've got gtx 1060 6gb) after reboot splash and logs show up normally, but when the login screen should show up there is only a black screen. For the login screen to show up I have to change my tty twice (first ctrl+alt+f1, then ctrl+alt+f2). After entering credentials the black screen shows up again and I have to switch to tty1 again for my desktop to show up (ctrl+alt+f1).
I tried different dms (gdm, sddm, lightdm), switch to X from wayland, nvidia_drm.modeset=1 in boot options. Logs seem to not show any errors.

Are you sure you are using the 2022-October release? ie. 22.10?

Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Please install 24.04
